# Inheriting from a class but using a subclass of an attribute

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have to implement a **Red/Black tree (RBTree)** in C++, inheriting from a **Binary Search Tree (BSTree)** class I already created.

The BSTree class **contains** a Node pointer (Node is a class I created for BSTree) to the tree root.

I want to create a Node subclass called "RBTNode", which contains color attribute and related methods (so **RBTNode is subclass of Node**), then I want to create the RBTree class inheriting from BSTree, but **with the new RBTNode** instead of the standard Node.

The structure would be as follows:

- BSTree **contains** Node;
- RBTNode **is** subclass of Node;
- RBTree **is** subclass of BSTree;
- RBTree **contains** RBTNode;

How could I achieve that?

Comment: With templating `Node` from `BSTree`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jarod42 in the comments, you can achieve this by making the node type a template parameter for the `BSTree` class.

Say you have these two node classes:

```cpp
template<typename KeyT>
class BSNode {
public:
    KeyT key;
    // ...
};

template<typename KeyT>
class RBNode : public BSNode<KeyT> {
public:
    bool color;
};
```

Then you could add a node type template parameter to `BSTree` and make it `BSNode` by default. You can then use `RBNode` while inheriting in `RBTree`.

```cpp
template <typename KeyT, typename NodeT = BSNode<KeyT>>
class BSTree {
protected:
    NodeT *root;
};

template <typename KeyT>
class RBTree : public BSTree<KeyT, RBNode<KeyT>> {
    // root will be of type RBNode<KeyT>* here
};
```

Comment: By the way, I am really not sure if my answer should include how to constrain BSNode to be the base class of NodeT.

Comment: Thank you bro, this works just fine and it seems a nice and versatile solution to my problem.